# Why is UIScrollView adding UIImageView subviews to its subviews when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uikit

If title isn't telling you anything, here's what I found out recently and am curious about:
In my app I have a UIScrollView with buttons in it. These buttons all have one subview each - an instance of UILabel. Sometimes there is a particular event triggered that changes the text in labels and I also needed to change the frame of both labels and buttons, so that whole text can be displayed (it won't be truncated). So I just grabbed first subview of a button and checked how much space its text needs.

This caused crashes if that event occurred during scrolling. Turns out that besides the label, each button had another subview which was instance of UIImageView. At first I thought that during scrolling, UIScrollView takes "screenshots" of its subviews and kind of puts the images on top so that animating the scrolling is somewhat less expensive in terms of performance. This logic is flawed however, because the UIImageView was a subview at index 0, so it was put below my labels.

Anyone knows why this happens? What did Apple engineers try to achieve with this weird mechanic?

Note that it might actually happen just for buttons though. Also, I checked the labels and they didn't have any subviews.

Answer (score 1):

`UIButtons` have a `UIImageView` for the background image (which is `nil` until you call `- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state` or set it using Interface Builder). So I would assume that the subview at index 0 would be the background image since that would be drawn first to be below everything else.

What you could do to be sure that you are getting the `UILabel` that you're looking for is something like this:

```
- (UILabel *)getLabelForButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    for (id subView in button.subviews)
    {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            return subView;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: My buttons don't have any background images and are transparent. Also, this only happens when scrolling in progress, otherwise the only subview is the label. Could have something to do with it though.

Comment: Just edited my answer to give you a suggestion for making sure you only pull out the label so you don't end up with an object that doesn't actually have a frame.

Comment: I fixed it already. I'm just asking here for ideas as to why the image view appears. Purely out of curiosity.